# Accessing NSDictionary inside NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.
Each dictionary in the array has three keys: 'Name', 'Sex' and 'Age'

How can I find the index in `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` where, for example, `Name = 'Roger'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    NSUInteger count = [array count];
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {  
        if ([[[array objectAtIndex: index] objectForKey: @"Name"] isEqualToString: @"Roger"])
        {  
            return index;
        }   
    }
    return NSNotFound;
```

Comment: Array indexes are unsigned integers. Use `NSUInteger` instead of `int`.

Comment: else was actually a comment... typooo

Answer (score 15):

On iOS 4.0 and up you can do the following:

```
- (NSUInteger) indexOfObjectWithName: (NSString*) name inArray: (NSArray*) array
{
    return [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:
        ^BOOL(id dictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [[dictionary objectForKey: @"Name"] isEqualToString: name];
    }];
}
```

Elegant, no?

Comment: This is what i get when use your function --

error: incompatible block pointer types initializing 'signed char (^)(struct NSDictionary *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)', expected 'BOOL (^)(struct objc_object *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)'

Comment: What will it return if it does not find the object?

Comment: @St3fan Your correction is incorrect -- the error @Nash mentioned is saying that the predicate block returns a `BOOL`, not `void` (as you have implied by omitting a return type from the block declaration).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using iOS > 3.0 you will be able to use the `for in` construct.

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in myArray) {
  if([[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:@"Roger"]) {
    return [myArray indexForObject:dict];
  }
}
```

Comment: Fast enumeration has always been available on the iPhone, also on 2.x.

Comment: This is not very efficient since you have to loop twice over the array. First to find the object that matches and then again to find it's index. It is better to use a simple for loop and `objectForIndex:` if you want to do it without blocks.

Answer (score -2):

There's method [NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest]. But it employs blocks, an Apple extension to C, and therefore is evil. Instead, do this:

```
NSArray *a; //Comes from somewhere...
int i;
for(i=0;i<a.count;i++)
    if([[[a objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey: @"Name"] compare: @"Roger"] == 0)
        return i; //That's the index you're looking for
return -1; //Not found
```

Comment: You shouldn't use -1 to mean "not found", you should use NSNotFound. It would also be more readable with isEqualToString: instead of compare:... == 0.

Comment: Given that Objective-C is also an extension to C, how are blocks more evil than Objective-C?

Comment: Downvoted because you think Blocks are evil. Blocks are the future, get used to it.

Comment: Also, instead of an int, use `NSUInteger` to index the array.

Comment: @St3fan: future is garbage-collected languages, not [Objective] C.

Comment: @smorgan: would it be a Microsoft-promoted extension to C, what'd you say?

Comment: @Seva aside from ARC, which is far superior in comparison to garbage collection, why shouldnt we use blocks in a garbage collected language?

Comment: I'm not saying we should not. I'm saying that proprietary (as opposed to standardized) extensions to C are evil.